# Single Source File for Grapes (@Grab) and imports for Use in Multiple Scripts

Tags: groovy

I would like to simplify my Groovy scripts by concentrating the same boiler-plate code at the beginning of each script that contains @Grapes (@GrabConfig and @Grab) as well as the multiple import lines.  In this way I can update a single source file when updates are required to simplify the maintenance of all of the scripts that utilize that boiler-plate code.

I understand that I can utilize the "--configscript" to simplify the import lines but I have not found a solution for the @Grapes boiler-plate lines.

I also understand that the @Grapes boiler-plate lines can be removed if I were to download the artifacts and place their dependent jar files on the classpath.  However, I really do like the simplified maintenance of not continually looking for downloads and classpath management.

Thanks in advance.